# Using Beautiful Soup to extract values from one of several tables

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from one table of several from a South African website.

https://www.capetown.gov.za/Family%20and%20home/residential-utility-services/residential-water-and-sanitation-services/this-weeks-dam-levels

what I am using right now for code:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.capetown.gov.za/Family%20and%20home/residential-utility-services/residential-water-and-sanitation-services/this-weeks-dam-levels"

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

dam_data_container = soup.find('table')
```

This returns pretty much all of the webpage, but what I am after is the table labeled as showing the weekly levels.

I know that I must use some attributes like div or id to find the right table, but every combination I use comes up as no results or syntax errors.

Comment: Looks like data comes from POST requests to this url: https://www.capetown.gov.za/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery  you can find it in the network tab. The post request looks like it returns json with _"ResultTables"_ as a key within.

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry I don't really understand. I am very new to this. Should I use this URL instead of the one I am using?